# AttributeError: GeoAxesSubplot.set() got an unexpected keyword argument 'gridspec_kw'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot consisting of 5 subplots and I want to shift the axis on each(from the right towards the left) to align with the straight edge. [spatial plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wafT8.jpg)

I have attempted to use "gridspec_kw" in "matplotlib" to accomplish this but i keep getting the error "AttributeError: GeoAxesSubplot.set() got an unexpected keyword argument 'gridspec_kw". I am not sure what I am missing here.
Here's a part of my code

```
f= plt.figure(figsize=(12,9), dpi=300,tight_layout=False)
inter = np.linspace(-5,5, num=11, endpoint=True)
lat = f222['xlat']
lon = f222['xlon']
ax1 = f.add_subplot(331, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(),gridspec_kw={'width_ratio':[2,1]})
pr = plt.contourf(lon, lat, f222.tmp.mean('time'),inter, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),cmap='RdGy_r',extend = 'both')
ax1.coastlines(resolution='50m',color='black')
x_lons  = np.arange(-20,20,10)
y_lats  = np.arange(5,25,5)
ax1.tick_params(labelsize=7)
lon_formatter = LongitudeFormatter(zero_direction_label=True,number_format='.0f')
lat_formatter = LatitudeFormatter()
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lon_formatter)
ax1.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lat_formatter)
tick_fs = 16
ax1.set_xticks(x_lons, minor=False, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax1.set_yticks(y_lats, minor=False, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax1.text(-23., 5.5, r'(a)', fontsize=7,fontweight="bold")
ax1.text(-15., 25, r'CRU - Grell', fontsize=10,fontweight="bold")
ax1.add_feature(cf.BORDERS, lw = 0.5)
ax1.add_feature(cf.COASTLINE, lw = 0.5)
ax1.coastlines(resolution='50m',color='black', lw = 0.5)
```

I am using matplotlib version 3.6.2. and I am relatively new to python.

Comment: From what I can tell from the docs, f.add_subplot doesn’t pass arguments down to a grid spec instance. It’s possible you are mistaking this function with the function “matplotlib.pyplot.subplots()”, which does in fact have a gridspec_kw argument. I’m not to familiar with matplotlib but this might be a viable solution to your problem.

Comment: I will have to look into this, thanks for the suggestion.